Why is my Python Pi calculator slowing down over time?
I recently saw this video that explained how to calculate pi, and attempted to build a Python simulation. In theory, it works, but it is much too slow, and I have no idea why.
In the output, you can see that the program starts off with hundreds of collisions calculated per second, but quickly slows down to only 40-50 per second, and when I leave it alone for a prolonged amount of time, it decreases to a measly 2 calculations!
Here is my code:
#imports
from time import time, sleep
from fractions import Fraction

#set variables
p = [Fraction(8, 1), Fraction(10, 1)]
m = [1, 1]
v = [Fraction(0, 1), Fraction(-1, 1)]
collisions = 0
time_interval = 1

#main
print("The π Calculator\n\nCredits:\nOriginal formula discovered by Gregory Galperin\nSimulation by Te Du\n")
sleep(1)
m[1] = 100 ** int(input("How many digits would you like to calculate? "))
start_time = time()
prev_time = start_time
while not (v[0] <= v[1] and v[0] >= 0):
    if time() - prev_time >= time_interval:
        try:
            print("Seconds elapsed: " + str(time() - start_time) + "\nCollisions: " + str(collisions))
        except ValueError:
            prev_time = time() + 1000000000
        time_interval = 2 - (time() - prev_time)
        prev_time = time()
    try:
        wall_to_one = p[0] / -v[0]
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        wall_to_one = 0
    one_to_two = (p[1] - p[0]) / (v[0] - v[1])
    collisions += 1
    if one_to_two <= 0 or (0 < wall_to_one and wall_to_one < one_to_two):
        p[0] += v[0] * wall_to_one
        p[1] += v[1] * wall_to_one
        v[0] *= -1
    else:
        p[0] += v[0] * one_to_two
        p[1] += v[1] * one_to_two
        v = [Fraction(m[0] - m[1], m[1] + m[0]) * v[0] + Fraction(2 * m[1], m[1] + m[0]) * v[1], Fraction(2 * m[0], m[1] + m[0]) * v[0] + Fraction(m[1] - m[0], m[1] + m[0]) * v[1]]

#cleanup
del p, m, v, wall_to_one, one_to_two, start_time, prev_time, time_interval

#printing pi
print("π: " + str(collisions))


What is the except ValueError: block for? Why would any of the numbers that you print cause a value error?

Calculations with arbitrary-precision numbers slow down as the number of digits increase. Addition and subtraction are O(n), while multiplication and division are O(n^2).

That is for if the collision count gets too big. Since now that prev_time is greater than time(), it will never call print() again and raise an error. (if you haven't learned already, I don't do things the normal way)

thanks @Barmar for the info, but is there any way I can speed this up?

Probably not if you need all those digits of precision. This is why we use floating point for ordinary numeric calculations. It's much faster, but not as precise.

Well, guess this project is gonna be scrapped. It was fun while it lasted though.

Maybe try one of the spigot algorithms? The nice thing is that you don't need to input a number of desired digits, as it just keeps going to produce more. See for instance this answer I posted for JavaScript.
